# Counting the number of words, numbers, uppercase and lowercase characters

Tags: c

I am a beginner programmer and there was this exercise I found that said:

> Write a string of characters and determine the number of words, numbers, uppercase and lowercase characters and spaces.

I thought I built a decent enough program and it works, kind of!

The problem is that when I try to run it the result is not entirely correct.

For example; When I write: `HI MY name is Ani 1 1 2 a`
it says that

- *Spaces = 8*. Correct here
- *Numbers = 3*. Correct here as well
- *Upper Case characters = 4*. It should be 5
- *Lower Case characters = 7*. It should be 9
- *Words = 26*. Which is completely wrong

As for the words, I found a new way to count them. By counting `spaces+1`, but I want to count them correctly.

Is it possible to point out the mistakes?

This is what I have done so far

```
int main() {
    char str[1000+1];
    int words = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int uppercharacters = 0;
    int lowercharacters = 0;
    int spaces = 0;
    int i;

    printf("Please enter the string of characters: ");
    gets(str);
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] > 'a' && str[i] < 'z')
            lowercharacters++;
        else if (str[i] > 'A' && str[i] < 'Z')
            uppercharacters++;
        else if (str[i] == ' ')
            spaces++;
        else if (str[i] > '0' && str[i] < '9')
            numbers++;
        else if (str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] != ' ');
            words++;
    }
    printf("Spaces = %d\n", spaces);
    printf("numbers = %d\n", numbers);
    printf("Upper Case characters = %d\n", uppercharacters);
    printf("Lower Case characters = %d\n", lowercharacters);
    printf("Words = %d\n", words + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the range in `if(str[i]>'A' && str[i]<'Z')` is correct? What are the "borders" of that range? What happens if the character is exactly 'A' or 'Z'?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica yeah. If the answer is => an =< i figured out the moment i posted. I still need some help with counting the words tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As for the words, I found a new way to count them. By counting `spaces+1`, but I want to count them correctly.

The code fails due to `;` at the end of the `else if()`.

**Tip**: Good compilers with all warnings enabled will warn about that.

Save time, and enable all warnings.

```
//                                   v !!!
else if(str[i]==' ' && str[i+1]!=' ');
    words++;
```

Even if corrected to

```
else if(str[i]==' ' && str[i+1]!=' ')
    words++;
```

it still fails with input like `" abc"` (lead space) reports as two words.

---

Instead, count the occurrences of a letter following a non-letter.

```
char previous = '\n';

for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
  if (isalpha(str[i]) && !isalpha(previous)) {
    words++;
  }
  previous = str[i];
}
```

Make your own helper functions if the standard ones, like `is...()`, are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')` instead of `if(str[i]>'a' && str[i]<'z')`. You don't want to exclude the characters z and a from being tested.

Comment: Just figured it out the moment i posted the question. Can you help me with the counting of the words. As i said in the question i found out that the number of the words is the number of the spaces +1 but i want lets say a "proper" or doing it

Answer (score 1):

For the counting words part, notice that there is one misplaced semicolon after your last `else if` statement. The number of words won't be 100% correct if you fix that typo, but you might be able to work from there :)

Comment: For the counting words part i already figured out another solution. If you count the spaces the words are spaces+1. But i dont understand why my solution is not working. In my head at least seems to be correct. Like if the first character is a space and the 2nd character is not this probably means that we have encountered a word and the total number is words+1